# Establish Mandatory-One to Optional-One

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Say I had three tables:

- Customer
- Vehicle
- Reservation

I want Customer to Reservation to be Mandatory-One to Optional-One (meaning a reservation requires one customer and a customer can have zero to one reservations).

Same thing for Vehicle: reservation requires one vehicle and a vehicle can have zero to one reservations.

How would I create these tables?

I tried creating each table with it's own ID column (C_ID, V_ID, R_ID) as PK and then creating FK constraints in Reservation table for C_ID (NOT NULL) and V_ID (NOT NULL), but this seems to allow a customer and vehicle to have multiple reservations.

Would the correct thing to do be apply unique constraint to C_ID and V_ID (individually) in the Reservation table?

**EDIT: Model tab screenshot from Oracle SQL Developer**
[image: Model tab screenshot from Oracle SQL Developer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, make the customer foreign key column unique in your reservations table.  Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE customers
  ( customer_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY ( customer_id ) );

CREATE TABLE reservations 
  ( reservation_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
    customer_id    NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT reservations_pk PRIMARY KEY (reservation_id ),
    CONSTRAINT reservations_fk1 FOREIGN KEY ( customer_id ) REFERENCES customers ( customer_id ),
    CONSTRAINT reservations_u1 UNIQUE ( customer_id )
  );

-- Fails, customer does not exist        
insert into reservations ( reservation_id, customer_id ) VALUES ( 100, 10 );  

-- Fails, reservation requires customer
insert into reservations ( reservation_id, customer_id ) VALUES ( 100, null );  

-- Fine.. Customer does not need a reservation;
insert into customers ( customer_id ) VALUES ( 20 );   

-- Fine.  One reservation for one customer
insert into reservations ( reservation_id, customer_id ) VALUES ( 200, 20 );   

-- Fails -- cannot have more than one reservation for same customer    
insert into reservations ( reservation_id, customer_id ) VALUES ( 201, 20 );
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I thought but wanted to be sure. I guess what I'm confused about is how Oracle SQL Developer shows the relationship. If you look at image I just added to my post, shouldn't it show |O next to Reservation and || next to Customer and Vehicle? Why does it show an arrow?

Comment: @cb1295 Sorry, I don't know off-hand how SQL\*Developer's data modeling feature works.

Comment: No worries, I at least know that it is working as it should, regardless of what the modeling shows

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then yes, you should create foreign key constraints linking the `reservation_ID` to the `Customer` and `Vehicle` tables since the reservation is unique to one customer and one vehicle.